# How to create a tab in ConEmu that runs as SYSTEM

Tags: windows, conemu

How do I set up a command that runs a new tab as SYSTEM, either using PsExec or in some other way?

Comment: I tried a shell command like so: `path\to\psexec -i -s cmd.exe`, but this just makes my main ConEmu window wait, and launches a standard console window through PSExec. I want a tab inside ConEmu instead. I imagine there's some hoops to jump through to attach the psexec created console window to an existing ConEmu instance, which is beyond me at the moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create task with following command:

```
cmd.exe -new_console:aA
```

---

Old deprecated version using psexec:

```
-new_console:abn C:\Tools\PsTools\psexec.exe -s -h -d -i "%ConEmuBaseDir%\ConEmuC64.exe" /ATTACH /GHWND=%ConEmuHWND% /ADMIN /ROOT cmd.exe
```

Comment: I get the following error `Unsupported task parameters

Task name: {Shells::SYSTEM}

Parameters: -new_console:abn C:\Work\CLITools\PsTools\psexec.exe -s -h -d -i "%ConEmuBaseDir%\ConEmuC64.exe" /ATTACH /GHWND=%ConEmuHWND% /ADMIN /ROOT cmd.exe`

Comment: Where I've said that **command** must be set in Task **parameters**???

Comment: My bad. This works flawlessly when entered in the 'command' field. Thanks!

Comment: @Maximus is it possible to use this in Session 0 -- I need it to troubleshoot System-run services (Tomcat), and I must be in the same session that the service was started from.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm connected via Remote Desktop if that makes a difference

Comment: Why it's not possible?

Comment: @Maximus, you said that `cmd.exe -new_console:aA` should do the job but it pops a new tab that immediately quits. The "Old deprecated" alternative works (ConEmu 190331). Is there something missing?

Comment: @j4x `cmd.exe -new_console:aA` works for me. If your shell exits - it's a question for your shell. You may turn on [log files](https://conemu.github.io/en/LogFiles.html), some useful info may be there.